# Why is my value undefined if I it is being added?

Tags: solidity

I have a contract that when testing, I get the following error even though I have added a value object:(I have also tried changing this to an array instead of being in object but without any luck)

```
Error: invalid value for array (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to why this does not work? I am using hardhat to create, compile, and run my testing file.

The error occurs on the following line in my testing script:

```
await deployedContract.addStudent(newStudent, {value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther('123456')})
```

Testing script below that I am using to make sure the contract function is working:

```
const main = async () => {
    const [owner, randomPerson] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const contract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('CollegeGrades');
    const deployedContract = await contract.deploy();
    await deployedContract.deployed();
    console.log('Contract deployed at: ', deployedContract.address);
    const newStudent = {
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        age: 55,
        wallet: owner.address
      };

    await deployedContract.addStudent(newStudent, {value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther('123456')})
} 

const runMain = async () => {
    try {
        await main();
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

runMain();
```

The following is my Solidity contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <=0.8.20;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract CollegeGrades {
    address payable public owner;

    // Struct to store information about a course
    struct Course {
        string name;
        uint credits;
        uint grade;
    }

    // Struct to store information about a student
    struct Student {
        string name;
        uint age;
        address payable wallet;
        Course[] courses;
    }

    // Mapping from student ID to student struct
    mapping(uint => Student) public students;

    // Counter to track the number of students
    uint public studentCount;

    // Event to be emitted when a student is added
    event StudentAdded(uint id, string name, uint age, address payable wallet);

    // Event to be emitted when a course is added
    event CourseAdded(uint id, string name, uint credits, uint grade);

    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    // Add a new student to the contract
    function addStudent(Student memory newStudent) public payable {
        
        require(newStudent.wallet == address(0), "Student with that wallet/address already exists !!!");
        
        // Geting student id
        uint id = studentCount++;

        // Setting all student values except courses
        students[id].name = newStudent.name;
        students[id].age = newStudent.age;
        students[id].wallet = newStudent.wallet;

        emit StudentAdded(id, newStudent.name, newStudent.age, newStudent.wallet);
    }

    // Add a new course to a student's record
    function addCourse(uint _studentId, Course memory newCourse) public {
        // Ensure the student exists
        require(students[_studentId].wallet != address(0), "Student does not exist");

        // Add the course to the student's record
        Student storage student = students[_studentId];

       // Adding new course to the array of all the Studen't Courses
        student.courses.push(newCourse);

        emit CourseAdded(_studentId, newCourse.name, newCourse.credits, newCourse.grade);
    }

    // Calculate the GPA of a student
    function getGPA(uint _studentId) public view returns (uint) {
        // Ensure the student exists
        require(students[_studentId].wallet != address(0), "Student does not exist");

        // Calculate the GPA
        Student storage student = students[_studentId];
        uint totalCredits = 0;
        uint totalPoints = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < student.courses.length; i++) {
            Course storage course = student.courses[i];
            totalCredits += course.credits;
            totalPoints += course.credits * course.grade;
        }
        return totalPoints / totalCredits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would make that function simpler to call and write it like: `function  addStudent(string memory _name, uint _age, address _wallet)`

Other wise try deploying on remix get the correct data type passed then use for your testing frame work

Comment: Tried breaking out the variables but got the same issue but didnt try with remix(never used it before but now my be a good time to trye)

Comment: Actually not sure what I did before when making the call more simple but that did solve my issue.